# Add tooltips to explain the reason for all reputation numbers

Tags: feature-request, reputation, tooltips

For example, on the [Reputation History](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33225?tab=reputationhistory) page, there are several numbers, positive and negative, which are very unclear. Hovering over the numbers should display a tooltip explaining what the reputation is for. (For example, “an answer of yours was upvoted”, “an answer of yours was accepted”, etc.)

Similarly, on the [Reputation tab of the Recent History page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/33225?tab=reputation), there are equally mysterious numbers that could be clarified with a tooltip.

Comment: A single number may be from multiple causes:  upvotes+accepted answer.

Comment: Is that something that is presented when we hit 1000 reputation? (See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: @kbrimington No, that just lets you see how many upvotes and downvotes a particular post has, instead of just `upvotes-downvotes`

Answer (score -2):

You really just can't figure that out?

```
+5 = Upvote (Question)
+10 = Upvote (Answer)
+15 = Accepted Answer
> +49 = Bounty

-2 = Downvote
-100 = Flag
```

If you really care go here: https://stackoverflow.com/reputation/

Comment: There's a collision between losing rep for giving a bounty and losing rep for flags; they can both show up as -100

Comment: “You really just can't figure that out?” — As you’ve demonstrated, it is impossible. Two upvotes for a question are indistinguishable from one upvote for an answer, for example. And what does “flag” mean? I’ve flagged more than 10 comments and definitely haven’t lost 1000 reputation from that. See how unclear this all is?

Comment: Regarding the link you gave: holy crap, *even more* numbers and *even fewer* explanations! What the hell do you guys call UI?

Comment: @Timwi an upvote and an accepted answer is highly distinguishable from 5 questions up votes. One can only happen for a question and can only happen for an answer.

Comment: @Chacha, If your assumption is that we shouldn't implement anything that we could figure out for ourselves, then SO itself wouldn't be needed would it? 60% of the questions can be solved with a reasonable level of Google-fu.

Comment: @devinb That is not what I'm saying. What I am saying is that I don't think we need tool-tips to break down a reputation listing that is quite simple, and frankly, not used that often.

Comment: It's used by @Timwi. And it makes sense that if it's *unusable*, then it won't become "used that often" =P I agree that it's fairly simple, but that's just because you and I both know the exact set of rep-modifiers. Not every user would know that.

Comment: @dwvinb It isn't used that often because it a graph. A small graph on the user table thats shows your reputation over time. The recent activity stream is far more useful for seeing your latest reputation. If the team were to improve this, it would be a waste. Especially compared to all the other more important things they could be doing.